# Free application to do scanning using just twain driver

Tags: windows-7, scanning, twain

I have a Sharp AR5220d - I've downloaded and installed correctly the TWAIN driver from Sharp's website.

Everything works smoothly but I'd like to use this scanner with a free application (better) or a small paid one like VueScan.

It works perfectly but since I'm unable to force the TWAIN driver utilization - I get fewer options and mainly I'm not able to use duplex.

Any hints on how to force the TWAIN driver?

Comment: windows? linux? osx?

Comment: Aw! Sorry for being dumb...

Windows 7 32 bit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Paperscan](http://www.orpalis.com/products/paperscan/) works with a TWAIN driver for scanners on the system.